# Computer won't start with GPU plugged in

Tags: graphics-card, troubleshooting

I'm having some issues with a computer that I built. When the GPU power is not plugged in, the computer boots and works fine. But after plugging in the GPU power, it fails to boot. All I get is a twitch of the fans, then nothing. Note that this is similar to the issues experienced in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/384569/computer-doesnt-start-when-graphics-card-plugged-in), except that my system boots fine if the GPU is in the PCIE slot. The issues only arise after I plug in the 6-pin power cord.

Some background: I've had this system for about a year and it's been working fine until now. The genesis of the problem was when I moved my audio card from one slot to another in an attempt to fix some white noise issues. It doesn't seem like that would cause any issues, and the problem persists even when the audio card is completely removed.

I think that I've fried my GPU, probably through an accidental bump or static discharge. However, I also suspect it could be power supply or even motherboard issue. Having an idea of which one to replace would be helpful, especially because I don't have access to another system to test components individually. I'm not sure if these symptoms are indicative of a specific problem, or if there is any good way to test where the problem is.

Some relevant specs:

- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z87X-UD3H ATX LGA1150
- GPU: EVGA GeForce GTX 660 2GB
- Power Supply: SeaSonic 650W ATX12V / EPS12V

EDIT: Waiting ~12 hours with the computer off and unplugged didn't help the issue, so I'm guessing that it isn't a weird capacitor issue. The computer also fails to boot if I use a different PCIE slot.

Comment: You have since removed the audio (for testing) ?   Then tested the GPU in the other PCI-E 16 slot?  Prefer never to attempt startup without the GPU power plugs installed, even for testing.  If they provide in the UEFI ability to downgrade the PCI-e (gen 2, etc) test with it downgraded, and any DMA gen lowered also.

Comment: If it is totally true that the system was working, you moved some stuff around, and your gpu is not firing up on the first try (or first few tries) it is possible that it can work still. been there done that, where the thing got all pickey could be charged caps, a state it was in, but eventually it did work. . . hope.

Comment: @Psycogeek Yea I've tested with the audio card completely removed, though the system was working fine with the audio card. Using a difference PCIE port didn't help either. I guess I'll try again tonight to see if ~12 hours of being unplugged helps. Thanks.

Comment: it is likely that the PSU or the GPU are a problem, but wait? that motherboard itself is user reviewed to having problems just like this, so just replace the whole thing :-p .  Test, well one testing would be to use the on-die grafics chip , and hard test both it and the cpu at the same time, to attempt to determine if the PSU acts up ever. that is about all I can think of without buying more stuff, having a GPU to trade into the slot for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has similar symptoms, it turns out it was a GPU issue. Computer is working fine with a new graphics card (GTX 970).